# How to pass a thunk or callback function into a redux action. Serializing functions in a redux store for modals and toast confirm notifications

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

When using a generic modal or toast with a confirm button, it becomes useful to be able to pass an action into this component so it can be dispatched when you click confirm.

The action may look something like this:

```
export function showConfirm({modalConfirm}) {
  return {
    type: 'MODALS/SHOW_MODAL',
    payload: {
      modalId: getUuid(),
      modalType: 'CONFIRM',
      modalConfirm : modalConfirm,
    },
  };
}
```

Where `modalConfirm` is another action object such as:

```
const modalConfirm = {
  type: 'MAKE_SOME_CHANGES_AFTER_CONFIRM',
  payload: {}
}
```

The `modalConfirm` action is dispatched inside the modal component using `dispatch(modalConfirm)` or even `dispatch(Object.assign({}, modalConfirm, someResultFromTheModal)`

Unfortunatley this solution only works if `modalConfirm` is a simple redux action object. This system is clearly very limited. Is there anyway you can pass a function (such as a thunk) in instead of a simple object?

Ideally, something full featured likes this:

```
    const modalConfirm = (someResultFromTheModal) => {
      return (dispatch, getState){
        dispatch({
          type: 'MAKE_SOME_UPDATES',
          payload: someResultFromTheModal
        })
        dispatch({
          type: 'SAVE_SOME_STUFF',
          payload: http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'api/v1/save',
            data: getState().stuffToSave
          })
        })
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ended up using string aliases to an actions library that centrally registers the actions.

Modal emmiter action contains an object with `functionAlias` and `functionInputs`

```
export function confirmDeleteProject({projectId}) {
  return ModalActions.showConfirm({
    message: 'Deleting a project it permanent. You will not be able to undo this.',
    modalConfirm: {
      functionAlias: 'ProjectActions.deleteProject',
      functionInputs: { projectId }
    }
  })
}
```

Where 'ProjectActions.deleteProject' is the alias for any type of complicated action such as:

```
export function deleteProject({projectId}) {
  return (dispatch)=>{
    dispatch({
      type: 'PROJECTS/DELETE_PROJECT',
      payload: http({
        method: 'DELETE',
        url: `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/projects/${projectId}`,
      }).then((response)=>{
        dispatch(push(`/`))
      }),
      meta: {
        projectId
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The functions are registered in a library module as follows:

```
import * as ProjectActions from '../../actions/projects.js';

const library = {
  ProjectActions: ProjectActions,
}

export const addModule = (moduleName, functions) => {
  library[moduleName] = functions
}

export const getFunction = (path) => {
  const [moduleName, functionName] = path.split('.');

  // We are getting the module only
  if(!functionName){
    if(library[moduleName]){
      return library[moduleName]
    }
    else{
      console.error(`Module: ${moduleName} could not be found.`);
    }
  }
  // We are getting a function
  else{
    if(library[moduleName] && library[moduleName][functionName]){
      return library[moduleName][functionName]
    }
    else{
      console.error(`Function: ${moduleName}.${functionName} could not be found.`);
    }
  }
}
```

The `modalConfirm` object is passed in to the modal by props. The modal component requires the `getFunction` function in the module above. The `modalConfirm` object is transformed into a function as follows:

```
const modalConfirmFunction = (extendObject, modalConfirm) => {
  const functionFromAlias = getFunction(modalConfirm.functionAlias);
  if(functionFromAlias){
    dispatch(functionFromAlias(Object.assign({}, modalConfirm.functionInputs, extendObject)));
  }
}
```

As you can see, this function can take in inputs from the modal. It can execute any type of complicated action or thunk. This system does not break time-travel but the centralized library is a bit of a drawback.

Comment: Do you still use this approch since the answer or have you moved on something different ?

Comment: Yep, this is the only system I could come up with that can withstand time-travel / application restarts or works in a multi-threaded electron app.

Nonetheless, when working in a single-threaded environment such as a website I just use a promise cache. This is a much nicer system to work with but not quite as robust...

You might make some sense of it here:
https://github.com/MrBlenny/react-redux-promise-modals/tree/master/src

The example is specific to modals but could be made generic. The id of a promise is passed around inside the action and then that promise is resolved/rejected

Answer (score 2):

Funny, putting an action object in the store and passing it as a prop to a generic dialog is *exactly* the approach I came up with myself.  I've actually got a blog post waiting to be published describing that idea.

The answer to your question is "Yes, *but*....".  Per the Redux FAQ at http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#organizing-state-non-serializable , it's entirely possible to put non-serializable values such as functions into your actions and the store.  However, that generally causes time-travel debugging to not work as expected.  If that's not a concern for you, then go right ahead.

Another option would be to break your modal confirmation into two parts.  Have the initial modal confirmation still be a plain action object, but use a middleware to watch for that being dispatched, and do the additional work from there.  This is a good use case for Redux-Saga.

Comment: I think the mentioned blog post would be https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/11/posts-on-packtpub-generic-redux-modals-and-building-better-bundles/ in case someone wants to read it

Comment: That post is mostly outdated. I did an updated version at https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/07/practical-redux-part-10-managing-modals/ .